# site taking too much time to load with domain name, but when I open with IP Address it works fine

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, asp, loading

I have a website which I have hosted on Windows 2008 R2 Dedicated Server.

Now, I have problem is my site taking almost 30 second to connect it through it's domain name any ".asp" pages. All other html and ".js" work fine so I don't think there is any dns issue.

But when I access those same pages with server IP address it opens in a second.

So the problem is opening any "Hello World" ".asp" page through domain name it takes almost 30 second.

Please advise me.

Server: Windows 2008 R2 Xenon DUAL CPU
IIS 7

Comment: If you have Server 2008 R2, you have IIS 7.5, not 7

Comment: I agree with kubanczyk below: this definitely sounds like a DNS-related slowdown from a reverse lookup somewhere in the chain. Are you logging remote client hostnames to your IIS logs or just IPs? Is the IP address you're coming from to the server something that can be reverse-looked-up? Are the JS and ASP files you're testing with in the same directory? Is the JS file being cached by your browser?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a DNS issue. Try to troubleshoot with:

```
nslookup your.url.com
nslookup 1.2.3.4     # bare IP address
ping your.url.com    # ping uses a system DNS resolver, so it differs from nslookup
```

Do this on both the client and the server.

Answer (score 3):

30 seconds is the tipoff - Your workstation has multiple DNS servers configured; the first is not working, and it takes 30 seconds to give up on that one and try the next.  Try the troubleshhoting steps above, and also:

```
nslookup your.url.com 4.2.2.2
```

(Really type 4.2.2.2, it's a public DNS server)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Google's public DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to see if it's a problem with the DNS servers you're currently using.

Answer (score -2):

I would advice you go with a managed DNS. They are usually more reliable than hosting your own and of course faster.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tested your site for performance holes, means your components like attached css, js, images can be on subdomain with different IP. I dont know the name of your website to tell you the actual problem, but suggest you to check website performance holes in http://zingro.com/. It may be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion).